# Resolving properties via eureka in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a simple `@EnableSidecar` for postgres app. with `virtual-host-name: postgres.vip` and `sidecar.port: 5432`. Can I in another `@EnableDiscoveryClient` app. have spring cloud resolve `@Value("${postgres.vip.port}")` or do I have to do the resolving manually via a `EurekaClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Value("${postgres.vip.port}")` won't work. You can use `EurekaClient` directly or use `org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient` which is an abstraction.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to do something like this https://gist.github.com/cmadsen/a84ee353154a841dae8e to avoid having to glue in the `EurekaClient` everywhere?